# Downloads via Tor Browser stop abruptly and then say they are finished

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, support

I make consistent downloads from a specific site. They begin normally, but abruptly stop, usually when they are 2% to 50% completed. After stopping abruptly a pop-up exclaims that all downloads are complete. Any way to fix this?

Comment: HTTP uses connection closing as a way to mark the end of the file. It seems like the SOCKS proxy translates interrupted connections to gracefully closed connections, causing Firefox to believe that it has finished the download (even when the http header claimed a larger file). At least that's my theory.

Comment: Could you say what site/download this is? Do you use plain Tor Browser or do you have plugins installed?

Answer (score -1):

This happens from Tor changing the exit relay and the server not being able to tell you are the same client from a different public IP.

Use a download manager like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/

Comment: Note that 3rd-party plugins may sacrifice security for convenience and are not recommended.

Comment: Tor does not break your circuits while there are still ongoing connections using them.